# how to scale the textfield ( a child of an accordion) relative to it's parent when resizing the window?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I added a textfield inside an accordion, with certain widths and heights. When scale the browser window, the width of the accordion changes relative to the window size but the width of the textfield remains the same and after a point, the text field goes out of the accordion.

The CSS for Accordion:

```
accordion1: {
    marginTop: '9%',
    border: '1px solid #54AF48',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    width: '250%',
    '&:hover': {
      flexgrow: '1', // what is it doing?
    },
  },
```

The css for Textfield:

```
form: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 150,
    width: '300%',
  },
```

I am unsure how can I fix this issue, anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's due to your minWidth attribute. When the accordion gets smaller than midWidth the textfield will end up going outside the accordion. I'd adjust that to make it smaller so it won't come up, add a minWidth to the accordion as well, or remove it altogether.

[Quick CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicaccordion-demo-material-ui-forked-000dl0?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Hi, I see what you are talking about but now the problem has been figured out. It was due to the fact the it was inside a container which was inside a different container and the grid sizes of them were not proportional. On setting them proportional to each other, the problem was solved.